# Определить, прошло ли с указанной даты 60 дней

Tags: c#

День добрый, требуется узнать, прошло ли с указанной даты определенное кол-во дней.
Я пытался сделать следующим образом, но осознаю, что это неправильно:

```
var datetimeToday = DateTime.Now.Subtract(new TimeSpan(60, 0, 0, 0));
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Now;
if (dateTime.Subtract(datetimeToday) == 60)
{
   // успешно
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DateTime inputDate = Ваше значение даты;

if ((DateTime.Today - inputDate) > new TimeSpan(60, 0, 0, 0))
{
//Успех.
}
```